# Low pass filter behavior in frequency domain

Tags: fft, filter-design, lowpass-filter, time-domain

I have a relatively simple task, which is to implement a low pass filter for a sum of exponentially dampen complex sinusoids in random Gaussian noise.

To showcase my problem I have generated data which consist of 6 frequencies being 502,504,506,620,622 and 624. The goal is to separate {502,504,506} from {620,622,624}

The data was generated with a sample rate fs=16025.641 and a total of N=33280 points.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate the data
np.random.seed(1)
alpha=np.array([2,1,2,2,1,2]) # decay rate 
A=([1000,2000,1000,1000,2000,1000]) # amplitude
omega=([500,502,506,620,622,624]) # frequencies
phi=([np.pi/12,np.pi/8,np.pi/8,np.pi/12,0,np.pi/12]) # phase

fs=16025.641 # sample rate

# define descrete time 
N=33280

vector=np.vectorize(np.float)
start_time=0
tn=np.arange(start_time, N,1)
tn=vector(tn)

# define continuous time
t=1/(fs)*tn

# define frequency axis
m=len(tn)
freq=(tn-math.floor(m/2))*fs/(m-1)

# data 
#y_complex=A * np.exp(-alpha*t) *np.exp(2j*np.pi * omega * t -phi) # equation

y_complex_re=[] # real part
y_complex_im=[] # imag part
for i in range(0,len(omega)):
    y_complex_re_temp=A[i] * np.exp(-alpha[i]*t)*np.cos(2*np.pi*omega[i]*t-phi[i])
    y_complex_im_temp=A[i] * np.exp(-alpha[i]*t)*np.sin(2*np.pi*omega[i]*t-phi[i])
    y_complex_re.append(y_complex_re_temp)
    y_complex_im.append(y_complex_im_temp)

y_complex_im1=np.sum(y_complex_im,axis=0)+np.random.normal(0,40,N)
y_complex_re1=np.sum(y_complex_re,axis=0)+np.random.normal(0,40,N)

y_complex=y_complex_re1+1j*y_complex_im1 # complex data

y_fft=np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(y_complex)) # freq domain data

# plot output 
plt.plot(t,y_complex)
plt.show()

plt.plot(freq,y_fft)
plt.xlim(440,660)
plt.show()
```

I now make a low pass filter with a cutoff at 550hz by using the scipy signal package. I choose a fir filter with the Kaiser window as it gives the option to control ripples and the width of the transition bands

```
import scipy.signal as signal
low_cut=550


# make low pass filter
ripple_db=60
nyq=fs*0.5
width=0.05*low_cut # transition band width
f_cut1= low_cut/nyq  # cutoff frequency

taps, beta = signal.kaiserord(ripple_db, width/nyq)  # taps and beta
low_filter=signal.firwin(taps,[f_cut1], window=('kaiser', beta)) # filter
y_low_passed=signal.filtfilt(low_filter,1,y_complex) # apply filter

y_low_passed_fft=np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(y_low_passed)) # filter in the frequency domain

plt.plot(freq,y_complex,color="blue")
plt.plot(freq,y_low_passed,color="red")
plt.show()

plt.plot(freq,y_fft,color="red")
plt.plot(freq,y_low_passed_fft,color="blue")
plt.xlim(300,800)
```

This looks ok but if I zoom in on the cutting point I get, for the lack of a better word, a "bump" in the frequency domain and if I look closely at the time domain it seems something has been added to the end and beginning of the time series

```
plt.plot(freq,y_fft,color="red")
plt.plot(freq,y_low_passed_fft,color="blue")
plt.ylim(-0.1*10**7,0.1*10**7)
plt.xlim(0,1800)
```

What is causing this behavior? and is there any way to mitigate this? I am relatively new to signal processing and have no background in electrical engineering (I am a statistician trying to do DSP). The answer might be obvious, but I have no idea myself :(

hope someone can help:)

Comment: Are you sure you want a ripple of 60 dB? I would try 1dB or 0,1dB for starters. The ripple is the allowable deviation from the ideal frequency response and you want this to be small not large.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. Mabye im missunderstading something then, the ripple db is that not the desired attenuation in the stop band? And ideally the best pass band ripple would be something close to 0? How do you set the passband ripple in the firwin with the Kaiser window? Also im open to other suggestions Than a fir filter tried playing around the butterord filter as well with no sucess though